# How to extract dynamic text from a tooltip on a mouse hover in RSelenium?

Tags: r, web-scraping, tooltip, rvest, rselenium

I'm trying to extract a particular text from the tooltip when the mouse cursor hovers on that location. I've attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftmDZ.png) of the webpage displaying the tooltip that I'm trying to fetch the opening odds for Pinnacle which is +100. When I right-click on that location and select Inspect, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc9U8.png). Surprisingly, I don't see +100 anywhere here. How can I extract +100 using RSelenium after navigating to this page? If it helps, the URL of this page is https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/austria/itf-m15-anif-men/heller-peter-sanchez-izquierdo-nikolas-Gxdm8kB5/?r=3.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Inspect result]